# The username on meta is not editable and does not reflect the username on the parent site

Tags: bug, status-completed

I recently changed my username on the main site (from `Crossbrowser` to `GoodEnough`), but meta hasn't followed. At first I thought I had to change it on meta's side, but there's no edit button.

Is it a caching problem that will be resolved in a few hours or is there really a problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the (recent) past we only synchronized reputation between the child-meta and parent site on the hour.  Total profile syncs required a login/logout, as you discovered.

This has been changed.  Now if you update your profile it will be pulled down to the child-meta site, though it may take an hour or so for it to occur.

Answer (score 2):

The rep is synchronized hourly (according to the FAQ) to the Meta site from the Parent site.  Perhaps when this is updated it also includes other details about your account?

Comment: It's been more than 1 hour and it hasn't updated yet. Does meta and the main site use the same account or are they considered different?

Comment: Oh.  I'm pretty sure they're the same account.  The user id matches between the parent and meta sites.  Have you tried logging out and logging back in?

Comment: @rchern I haven't tried logging out/in but should that really be the solution?

Comment: Why not?  If your username is loaded in to session, why would it necessarily check to reload that every time you load a page?

Comment: In that case, *we* should see the new name, and we do not.

Comment: I meant that I'd expect it to look up the username and then store it - not query the database for it each page load.  I really don't know though, just tossing out ideas.

Comment: Just to let people know, logging out then back in works, but I still think this bug should be fixed especially since the other users also don't see the updated name until I log out/log in.